# Equivalent codes, different results (Python, Mathematica)

Tags: python-3.x, wolfram-mathematica

These are two codes, one written with Python 3, and the other one written with Wolfram Mathematica. The codes are equivalent, and therefore the results (plots) should be the same. But the codes give different plots. Here are the codes.

**The Python code:**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from scipy.special import k0, k1, i0, i1

k=100.0
x = 0.0103406
B = 80.0

def fdens(f):
    return (1/2*(1-f**2)**2+f **4/2
            +1/2*B*k*x**2*f**2*(1-f**2)*np.log(1+2/(B*k*x**2))
            +(B*f**2*(1+B*k*x**2))/((k*(2+B*k*x**2))**2)
            -f**4/(2+B*k*x**2)
            +(B*f)/(k*x)*
            (k0(f*x)*i1(f *np.sqrt(2/(k*B)+x**2))
            +i0(f*x)*k1(f *np.sqrt(2/(k*B)+x**2)))/
            (k1(f*x)*i1(f *np.sqrt(2/(k*B)+x**2))
            -i1(f*x)*k1(f *np.sqrt(2/(k*B)+x**2)))
            )

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8), dpi=70)
X = np.linspace(0, 1, 100, endpoint=True)
C = fdens(X)
plt.plot(X, C, color="blue", linewidth=2.0, linestyle="-")
plt.show()
```

[the python result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8uhi.png)

**The Mathematica code:**

```
k=100.;B=80.;
x=0.0103406;
func[f_]:=1/2*(1-f^2)^2+1/2*B*k*x^2*f^2*(1-f^2)*Log[1+2/(B*k*x^2)]+f^4/2-f^4/(2+B*k*x^2)+B*f^2*(1+B*k*x^2)/(k*(2+B*k*x^2)^2)+(B*f)/(k*x)*(BesselI[1, (f*Sqrt[2/(B*k) + x^2])]*BesselK[0, f*x] + BesselI[0, f*x]*BesselK[1, (f*Sqrt[2/(B*k) + x^2])])/(BesselI[1, (f*Sqrt[2/(B*k) + x^2])]*BesselK[1,f*x] - BesselI[1,f*x]*BesselK[1, (f*Sqrt[2/(B*k) + x^2])]);

Plot[func[f],{f,0,1}]
```

[the Mathematica result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRXGy.png)
(correct one)

**The results are different. Does someone know why?**

Comment: They handle floating point differently ?

Comment: Maybe. However, the shift of the minima of the function is more than 0.4. I would not expect this from different float handling.

Comment: A good way to find the source of problem would be, take a sub-expression, check their values individually. Do this check recursively to reduce the size of problem.

Comment: Also, I think MMA involve symbolic execution. What happens if you use `Compile[]` in MMA?

Comment: I forgot to mention, the Mathematica result is the correct one. So the problem is in the python code.

Comment: @Kh40tiK is correct, Mathematica uses symbolic expressions: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html If the differences between the answers weren't so stark I would chalk it up to floating point error but I think this is out of that scope

Comment: watch out for integer division in python. try making `1/2` `1./2.`  (not an issue for mathematica)

Comment: Thanks, corrected. But is not the problem.

Answer (score 1):

From my tests it looks like the first order Bessell functions give different results. Both evaluate to Bessel(f * 0.0188925) initially, but the scipy version gives me a range from 0 to 9.4e-3 where wolframalpha (which uses a Mathematica backend) gives 0 to 1.4. I would dig a little deeper into this.

Additionally python uses standard C floating point numbers while Mathematica uses symbolic operations. [Sympy](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) tries to mimic such symbolic operations in python.

Comment: Thanks, will look deeper into it.